# How to make a fullchain.pem with certbot ?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certbot

i've used this command with certbot :

```
certbot --agree-tos  --email  buo@outlook.com certonly --webroot -w /code/ree/Cert/  -d ree.com -d www.ree.com
```

so i have 3 folders : accounts  csr  keys

with various file and 2 pem file in scr ...

0000_csr-certbot.pem  0001_csr-certbot.pem

How to make a fullchain.pem from csr ?

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need resides in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/ree.com`. It comprises of:

- cert.pem
- chain.pem
- fullchain.pem (this is what you want)
- privkey.pem